# Evitar self=this mediante el uso de funciones flecha ES6

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ecmascript-6

En una clase de JavaScript, tengo una función que llama a un callback utilizando una variable propia del constructor. Para no copiar la clase entera voy a escribir un ejemplo:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    async_print() {
        setTimeout( function() {
            console.log(this.bar);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Esto da error ya que `this` referencia al contexto de la función y no al del objeto `Foo`, por lo que lo tiendo a solucionar mediante el uso de una variable `self` que referencia a `this` cuando todavía es lo que quiero que sea. Por ejemplo:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    async_print() {
        const self = this;

        setTimeout( function() {
            console.log(self.bar);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, me quedo con la sensación de que el uso de una variable `self` es un apaño que debería de ser evitado. Sé que existe una solución mediante el binding, pero también he visto que en ES6 se puede llamar a una función flecha.

En la documentación para desarrolladores de Mozilla, se explica mediante  el uso de [este ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Funciones/Arrow_functions):

```
function Persona(){
  this.edad = 0;

  setInterval(() => {
    this.edad++; // |this| apunta al objeto Persona
  }, 1000);
}
```

Sin embargo eso sólo me funciona en el caso de tener que utilizar una función o actuar con una variable, pero no me sirve para obtenerla directamente. Es decir, no puedo retornar tal valor para utilizarlo por ejemplo en el `console.log`. Estamos hablando de un valor que utilizo muchas veces, por lo que no veo viable hacer una función flecha cada vez que necesite interactuar con él.

¿Qué me estoy pasando por alto? ¿Cómo puedo obtener ese valor dentro del callback?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quizá no entendí bien la pregunta, pero con las funciones flecha, accedemos al contexto de afuera por decirlo de alguna manera, accedemos al contexto de la clase `Foo` en este caso (con this) y **si** podemos obtener las  variables directamente.

Básicamente, en las funciones flecha no existe `this` **como contexto adentro de la función**, sino que toma el contexto desde donde se la llama, osea que es parecido al resto del código que está afuera de la función. No sé si me expliqué bien. Ejemplo:

```js
class Foo {
    constructor(bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    async_print() {

        console.log(this.bar);//<--el this es de Foo

        setTimeout( ()=>{
            console.log(this.bar);//<--el this es de Foo
        }, 1000);
    }
}


var a = new Foo("algo")

a.async_print();//algo, que es bar
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. En todo caso, lo que quería decir era si existe alguna forma de obtener tal variable, tal que, por ejemplo `const bar = ()=>{ return this.bar };` El problema si intento hacer eso es que si yo luego hago console.log(bar) me muestra por pantalla [Function]. No sé si me entiendes.

Comment: La idea final es no realizar una función flecha cada vez que voy a acceder a la variable, ya que la utilizo decenas de veces dentro del callback.

Comment: @WolfyLPDC No es necesario hacer `bar = ()=>{ return this.bar };` para acceder a bar de Foo, puedes hacer `bar = this.bar` o usar directamente `this.bar`. Cuando haces console de bar, si hiciste `bar = ()=>{ return this.bar };` te retorna la [Function] porque devuelve la definición de la función, para acceder tendrías que hacer algo como `console.log(bar())` que ejecuta la función, pero bueno, no es necesario como ya dije porque podemos acceder con this.bar directamente.

Comment: Creo que no has entendido mi pregunta pero leyéndote me ha venido la respuesta a la cabeza. Te doy la respuesta por válida porque supongo que quien pregunte por lo mío buscará tu explicación. Gracias.